# Is there a way to specify which words in the training phrase are fulfilling slots in Dialogflow through java sdk

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I would like to create an intent using the Dialogflow java-sdk. The problem is I am am able to create training phrases and slots but I am not able to alocate the specific word to the training phrase like we do in the dialogflow console.

I have checked and Dialogflow also does not do it by itself.
Below I have wrotten the code I am currently using and the functions I have used. This may not help but may help in providing info into the current method I am using .

Is there any function in the dialogflow java api that will help me to achive this.

```
public  OutputResponseDTO createIntent(CreateIntentInputDTO createIntentInputDTO)
{
    // Instantiates a client
    try (IntentsClient intentsClient = IntentsClient.create()) {

        // Set the project agent name using the projectID (my-project-id)
        ProjectAgentName parent = ProjectAgentName.of(createIntentInputDTO.getProjectId());

        //first check if intent already exists
        for (Intent intent : intentsClient.listIntents(parent).iterateAll()) {
            //logger.error(intent.getDisplayName()+"Inside delete!!!!!!"+createIntentInputDTO.getIntentName());
            if (intent.getDisplayName().equals(createIntentInputDTO.getDisplayName())) {
                logger.error("Inside delete!!!!!!");
                deleteIntent(createIntentInputDTO.getIntentName(),createIntentInputDTO.getProjectId());
            }
        }

        List<String> trainingPhrasesIP=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int l=0;l<createIntentInputDTO.getTrainingPhrasesParts().size();l++)
        {
            trainingPhrasesIP.add(createIntentInputDTO.getTrainingPhrasesParts().get(l).getPhraseName());
        }
        // Build the trainingPhrases from the trainingPhrasesParts
        List<TrainingPhrase> trainingPhrases = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String trainingPhrase : trainingPhrasesIP) {
            trainingPhrases.add(
                    TrainingPhrase.newBuilder().addParts(
                            Part.newBuilder().setText(trainingPhrase).build())
                    .build());
        }

        // Build the message texts for the agent's response
        Message messages = Message.newBuilder()
                .setText(
                        Text.newBuilder()
                        .addAllText(createIntentInputDTO.getMessageTexts()).build()
                        ).build();



        List<Parameter> parameters=new ArrayList<Intent.Parameter>();

        for(int j=0;j<createIntentInputDTO.getSlotsInputDTOs().size();j++)
        {

            //String firstFourChars = createIntentInputDTO.getSlotsInputDTOs().get(j).getEntityDisplayName().substring(0, 5);
            //System.out.println(firstFourChars);

            String paraNameWithoutAtTwo;
            String paraNameWithoutAtOne;
            String paraNameWithoutAtAndWithDollar;
            String paraNameWithAt;

            try
            {
                paraNameWithoutAtOne=createIntentInputDTO.getSlotsInputDTOs().get(j).getEntityDisplayName().replace("@sys.", "");
             paraNameWithoutAtTwo=paraNameWithoutAtOne.replace("@", "");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                paraNameWithoutAtTwo=createIntentInputDTO.getSlotsInputDTOs().get(j).getEntityDisplayName();
                logger.info("Something happended when removing stuff");
            }

            paraNameWithoutAtAndWithDollar="$"+paraNameWithoutAtTwo;
            paraNameWithAt="@"+paraNameWithoutAtTwo;
            paraNameWithoutAt=createIntentInputDTO.getSlotsInputDTOs().get(j).getEntityDisplayName();



            Parameter parameter=Parameter.newBuilder()
                .setValue(createIntentInputDTO.getSlotsInputDTOs().get(j).getValue())
                    .setDisplayName(paraNameWithoutAtTwo)
                    .setValue(paraNameWithoutAtAndWithDollar)


                    .setEntityTypeDisplayName(createIntentInputDTO.getSlotsInputDTOs().get(j).getEntityDisplayName())
                    .build();
            parameters.add(parameter);
        }




        // Build the intent
        Intent intent = Intent.newBuilder()
                .setDisplayName(createIntentInputDTO.getDisplayName())
                .addMessages(messages)
                //                  .addParameters(p)
                                    .addAllParameters(parameters)
                .addAllTrainingPhrases(trainingPhrases)
                .build();




        // Performs the create intent request
        Intent response = intentsClient.createIntent(parent, intent);

    //  System.out.format("Intent created: %s\n", response);


        try
        {
            IntentMasterCollection intentMasterCollection=new IntentMasterCollection();
            intentMasterCollection.setName(createIntentInputDTO.getDisplayName());
            intentActionMaster.save(intentMasterCollection);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            logger.error("Error adding in DB intent master");
        }

        try
        {
            //we gonna put the data again!(Training phrases only)
            String[] splitName = response.getName().split("/");
            //              intentIds.add(splitName[splitName.length - 1]);



            //finally setting all the values

            updateIntent(splitName[splitName.length - 1]);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            logger.error("Error in writing to intent");
        }
        return new OutputResponseDTO(true, message.getStatusCode("success.message.createIntent.id"),
                message.get("success.message.createIntent"), null,  null,requestBean.getTraceId());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        logger.error("Error Creating Intent:"+e.getMessage());
        return new OutputResponseDTO(false, message.getStatusCode("error.message.generalError.id"),
                message.get("error.message.generalError"), null,  e.getMessage(),requestBean.getTraceId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you're having is related to Parts definition. 
Every training phrase is split into parts, and for each part, you can define if it is just text or if it contains an entity:

```
        Part part1 = Part.newBuilder().setText("I want to cancel a card ended in  ").build();
        Part part2 = Part.newBuilder().setText("5123").setEntityType("@cardNumber").setAlias("cardNumber")
                .setUserDefined(true).build();
        List<Part> parts = new ArrayList<Part>();
        parts.add(part1);
        parts.add(part2);
```

Then you build the training phrase:

```
    TrainingPhrase tp = TrainingPhrase.newBuilder().setType(Type.EXAMPLE).addAllParts(parts).build();
```

Comment: when tried to add multiple Training phrases then IsList option automatically check can suggest to me how to avoid that check?